# how to extract word from {} and print into a new line

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

input file has line like below

```
Line 21800: Value: $${scripts-dir1}part_archive_ret_hist_stg.ksh $${databse-name}
Line 32456: Value: $${log-dir}rollback.ksh $${databse-name}
```

How can I extract the word from {} and print to a new line in unix ?

Output should be like

```
scripts-dir1
databse-name
log-dir
databse-name
```

Comment: Sorry for the spam, don't know the answer, just here to say I love the typo in the title :D

Comment: i have searched for similar kind in google, couldnt find any working command, so posted here

Answer (score 1):

```
$ LINE='Line 21800: Value: $${scripts-dir1}part_archive_ret_hist_stg.ksh $${databse-name}'
$ echo "$LINE"|grep -oP '{\K[\w-]*(?=})'
scripts-dir1
databse-name
```

Actually your should update your question with more examples..
For unix you can try with awk, but the following will works only if you have two cases per line:

```
$ LINE='Line 21800: Value: $${scripts-dir1}part_archive_ret_hist_stg.ksh 
$ echo $LINE|awk -F "[{}]" '{print $2"\n"$4}'
scripts-dir1
databse-name
```

Comment: grep -oP is not working 

grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- P


OS is  SunOS

Comment: If you have just two cases per line, you can try awk: echo $LINE|awk -F "[{}]" '{print $2"\n"$4}'